# logistic regression for weak predictors

Tags: r, classification

Could some one suggest a method for gaining high accuracy with weak predictors in logistic regression?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In generally it is not possible. Some phenomenas are such that it is very difficult to predict them via variables which one has available.